# Getting contacts who own an iDevice

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, abaddressbook

Is there a way through addressbookUi framework to get only the contacts who own an iDevice? The check for example is done in the messages app for iMessage. But is this available for developers? Or is there another way to check for this? Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 2):

You could check, for each address book record, if there is a phone number of type "iPhone" (represented by the constant `kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel`). There's really no way of knowing for sure which of the contacts "owns an iDevice" anyway, but if there is an iPhone number for them in the address book record, then there's a good chance of them using an iPhone. Of course, it's another story altogether how that information got in your address book, and whether it is reliable.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't... The SMS app would be checking with apples servers to see if the phone number is registered with iMessage or not.

This is not a publicly accessible API.

I guess you could hash then send the users number to your own remote database and then compare contact numbers in another users address book against your database to see if they are users of your app... It's not really what you asked to do but it's the closest solution I could think up